# Apache2 não interpreta PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache

Instalei normalmente o PHP e o APACHE2 porém ele não interpreta os codigos PHP, segue codigo teste:

```
<?php echo "teste";
```

Ele me retorna uma pagina "html" com isso escrito, e vem de um "print" escrito teste

Os arquivos sem encontram na pasta /var/www/html com permissões 755 
Não alterei nada nas configurações do apache2 só dei start

Li sobre alteração no arquivo httpd.conf porém não acho dentro do meu sistema

Comment: E você colocou o código PHP dentro de um arquivo `.html`? Você configurou o Apache para interpretar arquivos HTML com o PHP? Se não, por quê não um arquivo `.php`? Aliás, evite utilizar termos de baixo escalão por aqui; ninguém se importa com quanto estressado com o seu código você está. Seja breve e claro, sempre.

Comment: Já testou alterando a extensão do arquivo para .php?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Peço desculpas, agora que vi. Sim já tentei colocar com uma extensão .php, porém ele ainda me retorna como se fosse um "HTML", estou colocando em var/www/html, será que o problema está na pasta...

Comment: Não deveria, se o Apache (ou outro servidor) estiver executando corretamente. Pode colocar na pergunta o código original do arquivo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Alterado, como disse a cima li sobre umas alterações no arquivo httpd.conf, porém, não estou encontrando

Comment: O arquivo inteiro é só essa linha PHP? Não tem mais nada nele? Porque na imagem que havia postado anteriormente era exibido a palavra "teste" na tela.

Comment: Então, a imagem que tinha postado era um codigo HTML com uma parte em PHP... Agora para simplificar e ser mais direto coloquei o arquivo em uma extensão .php e coloquei para que me retornasse uma mensagem de teste... Porém ainda não obtive sucesso pois eu acho que o APACHE2 não está conseguindo interpretar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tive o mesmo problema, resolvi instalando o módulo de php do apache, no meu caso utilizo o ubuntu bastou instalar esse pacote **libapache2-mod-php5**

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```